# Button text size is presented differently in two different fragments on S5 with android 5.0

Tags: android

I'm using same adapter, same list item layout for the lists in two different fragments but somehow textSize of a button is larger in one of them even if I have defined size in xml.

I have to mention that there is no difference in button text size when I test on S3 for instance which is android 4.3.

[image: Normal size]

[image: Magnified size]

Layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bFollow"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ib_follow"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_follow"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/m_orange"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Can someone offer any explanation on this?

Answer (score 0):

The first fragment (top) shows text without capslock
The second fragment (bottom) shows the same text with capslock

The textSize is the same of both.

Look at the code, which says the button, what it should show.

e.g. textView.setText(...);

Comment: But when I test app on S3 with 4.3 Android texts are the same in both fragments...